# Eliminating SubQueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am looking for a possible way if any to eliminate subquery.

Any comment would be helpful

```
SELECT
    [FacilityGroupID]
    ,[LocationGroupID]
    ,[MsrID]
    ,CAST(LEFT([ReportingPeriod],4) + '-' 
                + RIGHT([ReportingPeriod],2)
                + '-01' as datetime) as create_timestamp
    ,SUM([Denominator]) as [Denominator]
    ,SUM([Numerator]) as [Numerator]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT
        Tob.FacilitygroupId
        ,Tob.LocationgroupId
        ,Tob.Reportingperiod
        ,Tob.Denominator
        ,DimIndicator.MsrId
        ,CASE
            WHEN DimIndicator.MsrID = Tob.MsrId THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END as Numerator

    from
        BIReport.dbo.vIndianatest "Tob"
            INNER JOIN [BIreport].[dbo].[DimIndicator] "DimIndicator"
                on Tob.MsrSubGroupId = DimIndicator.MsrSubGroupId
) as "Inner"

GROUP BY
    [FacilityGroupID]
    ,[LocationGroupID]
    ,[MsrID]
    ,CAST(LEFT([ReportingPeriod],4) + '-' 
                + RIGHT([ReportingPeriod],2)
                + '-01' as datetime)
```

As with subquery, performance is way too slow.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `DISTINCT`?  Please also post the explain plan for the query.

Comment: The values of Denominator and Numerator summed up from the inner query are summed in the outer query

Comment: If you run just the nested select, is that too slow? And have you looked at indexes?

Comment: I know you're trying to put the date/time as a 'international' (ISO) form before the conversion, but unfortunately SQL Server regards that particular format as still localizable (check the first [first few paragraphs of this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)) - you'd be better of removing the dashes.  Also, is `ReportingPeriod` is a date/time type already?  There's probably a better (and more performant) function to get the start of the month.

Comment: So, the real goal is to speed up the query; as in, there may be other solutions to increase performance.

Comment: date is not a concerned, I was more concerned with removed the subquery if possible

Comment: what format at a ReportingPeriod?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `WITH`? `With` make subquery to inline views.

General use of `with`:

```
with clausename AS
(
subquery
)
main query referencing clausename;
```

Example:

```
-- define with clause
with saletot as
    (
     select dname, sum(sal) as dept_total
     from emp, dept
     where emp.deptno = dept.deptno
     group by dname
    )
-- Main query which use the with clause
   select dname, dept_total
   from saletot        -- Reference to with clause
   order by dept_total desc;
```

Comment: if you use the with clause to the select, where the join happens, the join is running only one time, i think so.

Comment: i mean in this way: with inner as SELECT DISTINCT Tob.FacilitygroupId ... from
BIReport.dbo.vIndianatest "Tob" INNER JOIN [BIreport].[dbo].[DimIndicator] "DimIndicator"  ...
SELECT [FacilityGroupID],[LocationGroupID]..,SUM([Denominator]) as [Denominator] ,SUM([Numerator]) as [Numerator] from inner
GROUP BY ...